# What are my options to run .Net Core App 24 X 7 in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-worker-roles

What are my options in Azure where my App should be up & Running 24 X 7 ?
The app is intended to receive events.
I don't need Invokable URL to receive the event, it is happening inside the code itself.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem. What did you end up with finally? One solution would be to run the app in VM but I hope there is more managed solution (with restricted restarts or something)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your code to azure web jobs and make it continuous trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs